# Can you see your own questions or answers in a review queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queue

Basically what the title says. Is it possible to see your own posts in a review queue? Of course it's bad practice at the very least to review your own posts or whatever. However I'm trying to figure out if an edit went through and I can't tell if it did or not.

Comment: You should be able to see your [suggestions on your profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/137615/peter-nielsen?tab=activity). (That link is for all your activity, but you can filter it down to just suggestions, too.)

Comment: Note that at the point you have enough reputation to review the edit queue, you will also have enough reputation that your edits won't go through the queue.  (Exception:  tag wiki edits.)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234543/236563

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't *review* your own posts/actions, and they won't appear for you as you browse the review queue. But you can check their status if you have a direct link to the review item.

As Null mentioned, links to your own suggested edits can be found from [your profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Links to review items for a post (if it went to the First Questions/Answers or Late Answers or Low Quality Posts or Close/Reopen Votes queues) can be found in the post history page *after* the review is completed: for example, you can see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/244024/timeline) who reviewed your first post on the site. However, there's no easy guaranteed way for non-mods to get those links while the review is still active. One possibility is going to the main /review page, where you can see who's reviewed most recently in each queue, and check the most recent reviews of those people (review actions are also visible in profile activity pages), but that's time-consuming and not guaranteed.